# Masking an EditorFor Model's integer value with Asterisks

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following code in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @tabIndex = 4 } })
```

My Model has:

```
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
        [Display(Name = "Badge")]
        [Required]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to get the input for the employeeId textbox to become asterisks as if it was a password. I can't use the PasswordFor tag since we don't want this to be saved by the browsers or prompted.

I know I can change the actual value when the field loses focus in jQuery but it seems that setting the field text doesn't work for some reason and it keeps displaying the numeric value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#EmployeeId').focusout(function () {
        $(this).text('***');
    })
</script>
```

Is there a way to get this to display an asterisk for each digit inputted by the user while keeping the real value in the model?

Much Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to mask text with asterisks is to use an input type of "password", which can be used for any type of information you want obfuscated like this, not just passwords.

`EditorFor`, however, is a "templated" helper, which is to say that it renders HTML for a modifying a property via a Razor view. The view that's used is based on the type of the property, a member of the `DataType` enum that's applied, or explicitly via something like `UIHint`. In the case of your property here, that would be `Int32.cshtml`, since it's an int. However, I doubt you'd want to apply this to every single int property, so you'd want to either do add `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` or `[UIHint("Obfuscated")]`, which would correspond to a `Password.cshtml` or `Obfuscated.cshtml` view, respectively.

These views would reside in `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` or `Pages\Shared\EditorTemplates`, depending on which style you're employing. The `UIHint` attribute can be set to anything (I just chose "Obfuscated"). Whatever you put there as the string is what the corresponding view will need to be named.

Now, assuming none of those things are true: there's no `Int32.cshtml` editor template view, and the `DataType`/`UIHint` attributes have not been applied, then `EditorFor` will fallback to a default template, which is for an int prop will be an input of type "number". In ASP.NET MVC 5, it was possible to add/modify HTML attributes in these default templates only by passing an anonymous object with an `htmlAttributes` member, which itself was an anonymous object of attribute names and values:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmployeeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "password" } })
```

I'm not sure if this works the same in ASP.NET Core or not, as I've never needed to try, but you can give it a shot, if you like.

In general, it's far better to just use the tag helpers anyways, though. Instead of using `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmployeeId)`, you can just do:

```
<input asp-for="EmployeeId" />
```

Then, you can easily make it a password field via:

```
<input asp-for="EmployeeId" type="password" />
```